# Initcap usage for built in types in Python

Tags: python, types

Python build in data types seem to usually have constructor names that start with lower case (set, list etc). But the data type seems to be init capped in some cases.

See example below. The constructors are lower cased while the types are init capped (see list and set constructor call). The same conventions is not followed when we call the constructor of newly defined classes (see the Solution constructor call).

```
class Solution:
    def intersection(self, nums1: List[int], nums2: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        set1 = set(nums1)
        set2 = set(nums2)
        print(set1.intersection(set2))
        return (list(set1.intersection(set2)))
sol = Solution()
```

In Java a general rule of thumb was primitive datatypes that didn't have constructors were lower cased (char, int etc) while Class based ones were init capped. What are similar conventions in Python?

Comment: Nit: those aren't constructors, they are the types themselves (types are first-class objects; the standard way of instantiating a class is to call it, which typically invokes the type's `__new__` method).

Comment: Built-in types are typically simple, lowercase names. Other classes use ThisNamingScheme. See [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the naming scheme. As I dig in deeper, this seems to be because [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) defines [List](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List) as a generic over [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list).

Comment: There's a subtle distinction: `List` is a type *hint*, not a type. Function annotations can use both types and type hints, but you cannot use a type hint in place of a type.

Comment: @Mojojojo this seems like a discussion and there's no actual programming issue you're having a problem with, please refer to the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
The simplest rule of thumb is to ask yourself; would I ask this question of a busy colleague?